# Mysql num rows without submitting form

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jquery php mysql query, which works fine, but before my form being submitted, I would like to tell my visitors how many results will they receive. For example: Show results (5).

Could you tell me an easy way of doing that please?

I would really appreciate it.

edit: my ajax looks like the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(){
 var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

 try{
   // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
   ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }catch (e){
   // Internet Explorer Browsers
   try{
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   }catch (e) {
      try{
         ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }catch (e){
         // Something went wrong
         alert("Your browser broke!");
         return false;
      }
   }
 }
 // Create a function that will receive data 
 // sent from the server and will update
 // div section in the same page.
 ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
   if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
 }
 // Now get the value from user and pass it to
 // server script.
 var bedno = document.getElementById('bedno').value;
 var district = document.getElementById('district').value;
 var loc = document.getElementById('location').value;
 var queryString = "?bedno=" + bedno ;
 queryString +=  "&district=" + district + "&location=" + loc;
 ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + 
                              queryString, true);
 ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Use `AJAX` to fetch number of results on submit form

Comment: using `jQery AJAX` call, you can do this without submitting form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AJAX` is right.
In your `ajax-example.php` file fetch the result using your parameters.
And echo the result.
example

```
 $st = mysqli_query($link, "your query");
 $result = mysqli_num_rows($st);
 echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the only problem is that this will only show the result after I click submit.

Comment: then you need to check all the field of form are filled, if it's filled then run the AJAX, if not the show message or do nothing. if it's helpful then don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: My last question is, I echo $numrows, but the place where I want to show that is not inside the ajaxDiv, how can I echo it outside the ajaxdiv?

Comment: <input type="button" value="Show $numrows" />

Comment: Add one attribute `id` `<input type="button" value="Show" id="result" />` and in your ajax change `ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText` to this `ajaxDisplay.setAttribute("value",ajaxRequest.responseText)` and set id `var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('result')`